# How to add a text description on an each image with jQuery on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add a text description on an each image with jQuery on click?

```js
$('.portfolio img').on('click', function() {

  var src = $(this).attr('src');

  $('#main').attr('src', src);
  $('.frameimg').fadeIn();
  $('.overlay-frame').fadeIn();

});

$('.overlay-frame').on('click', function() {

  $(this).fadeOut();
  $('.frameimg').fadeOut();


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filternav">
  <div class="frameimg">
    <img id="main" src="" alt="">
  </div>

  <ul class="portfolio">
    <li class="ALL SAD aizen"> <img src="img/characters/aizen.jpg" alt="">
      <p class="pshow aizen">ATT:738 DEF:342</p>
    </li>

    <li class="ALL SAD byakuya"> <img src="img/characters/byakuya.jpg" alt="">
      <p class="pshow byakuya">ATT:738 DEF:342</p>
    </li>

    <li class="ALL SAD barragan"> <img src="img/characters/barragan.jpg" alt="">
      <p class="pshow barragan">ATT:738 DEF:342</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the contextual `this` keyword. Something which you may want is:

```js
$(function () {
  $("img").click(function () {
    $(this).next("figcaption").fadeIn();
  });
  $("figcaption").click(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
.portfolio ul li {display: inline-block; text-align: center; position: relative;}
.portfolio ul li img {display: block; cursor: pointer;}
.portfolio ul li figcaption {display: none; position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); line-height: 100px; cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="portfolio">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <figure>
        <img src="//placehold.it/100?text=1" alt="">
        <figcaption>Image 1</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
      <figure>
        <img src="//placehold.it/100?text=2" alt="">
        <figcaption>Image 2</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
      <figure>
        <img src="//placehold.it/100?text=3" alt="">
        <figcaption>Image 3</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
      <figure>
        <img src="//placehold.it/100?text=4" alt="">
        <figcaption>Image 4</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
      <figure>
        <img src="//placehold.it/100?text=5" alt="">
        <figcaption>Image 5</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this is a very cool way to do this, i will definitely try it. i wrote in the top of my question jQuery code for my modal image gallery, now i want when i clicked on the image (image size increased, overlay and frame show),show text for specific image. example:

Comment: when i click on aizen picture i want to show me his stats

Comment: @mecanovovic Make sure you have the CSS width and height set.

Answer (score 0):

To have a text apear over an image when your mouse is over it simply add the title attribute to it like this;

```
<img src="img/characters/aizen.jpg" alt="" title="Your text here">
```